# Session is not removed after any event in asp.net vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session, logout

I am working on an asp.net project using vb.  I have a session.clear in my code and it only work if the user did not do any action after loading the page. I mean that if any event occurred, a button click for example ( even if the button click has no code) then if the user clicked logout, the session will be cleared but not in that page ( he can click back and return, but he can not open any other page because the session is cleared there)

Comment: Have you seen [session logout in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9043182/session-logout-in-asp-net)?

Comment: The problem is not with the logout button. For example, if I enterd page1 and clicked on logout then I can not return to that page again until I sign in. But the problem is that if I entered the page and clicked on a button inside that page ( a control event occured ) then if I clickec on logout I can return to that page ( but not other pages ). I think that this might  be something with the postBack but actually idk becuase I am new to these things.