# Session Fixation Vulnerability in ASP.NET MVC - .NET version framework 4.7.2

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm working in a vulnerability about Cookie ASP.NET_SessionId that is generate always that someone realize log in in the application.
The reproduction for this vulnerability is:
Reproduction

1. Browse to website
2. Log into the site, obtain a session cookie and logout
3. **In another browser**, *add the session cookie to in the developer tools* (Here I add manually the SessionId in the console of developerTools like document.cookie = "ASP.NET_SessionId=value_cookie_session_here";
4. In this same browser that I added manually the cookie Session_Id I try Log into the site and I note the session cookie is not updated, that is, instead of generating another one, the value of the session_Id is exactly what I defined manually in the developer tool **(Here is the vulnerability)**

Basically, Upon logging into the web site, the application should destroy the current session cookie and return a new one.

What I already did?

I implemented in the Logout method:

```
if (Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"] != null)
        {
            Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Value = string.Empty;
            Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-20);
        }
```

Basically, with this implementation, when I do Log in, after Logout and Log in again the Cookie Session_Id is updated (OK). But, when I reproduced the step by step above, I can't make the Session_Id updated when someone setting the Session_Id manually. I already tried input this code below in the Login method before Session and authentication definition, but the result is: I can do once log in, after logout and when I try do Log in again, I can't authentic myself, same the method return true and url successful.

```
if (Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"] != null)
        {
            Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Value = string.Empty;
            Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-20);
        }
```

***Thank you for your help!***

Comment: You need to do a bit more to log out: [session logout in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9043182/session-logout-in-asp-net).